# Vagrant doesnt open my fuelphp project

Tags: vagrant, fuelphp

I was using a computer with an already configured Vagrant/VirtualBox ambient. Now, I need to put this box in another computer.

So, I do the *vagrant package* and added the box in my new computer.

So when I go *vagrant up* and *vagrant ssh* everything looks perfect, and all my files are there.
But when I try to access my localhost, vagrant just show me "It Works" page.

I guess I'm missing some reference or link to my project or something like that.

I'm using Ubuntu in both computers and my project use FuelPhp.

Comment: Where are project's directory? In /var/www?

Comment: Nope. They are in /vagrant/educarebr.

The /var/www are empty. To access the files in my old computer, I had to put the http://educare.local address. I guess previous developer create a subdomain or something like that. But when I try to access educare.local in my new computer, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options here.

#### First Option

Use a [synced folder](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) in your Vagrantfile

e.g

`config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www"`

This will change your share folder mount in `/vagrant/educarebr` to `/var/www` and Apache will see the folder.

#### Second Option

Create a symbolic link in [vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html) using a provisioner, as Shell Script.

#### Third Option

Create a new [virtual host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts) in your Apache with DocumentRoot /vagrant/educarebr.

However, check your old Vagrantfile and compare with your new Vagrantfile that you are using with box created with vagrant package.

Comment: The trird option was the solution. Thanks a lot for your help!